# Blank view in root controller when extending UINavigationController on iOS 5, but working on iOS 6

Tags: ios5, ios6, xamarin.ios

I found some a very strange behavior when extending (inheriting from) `UINavigationController`. Consider the following:

```
public class MyNavigationController : UINavigationController
{
    public MyNavigationController(UIViewController viewRootController) 
    : base(viewRootController)
    {
        AllNavigationControllers.Add(this);
    }
}
...
window.RootViewController = new MyNavigationController(new AnotherController());
```

This works on iOS 6, but shows a blank view in iOS 5 instead of showing `AnotherController`'s main view (loaded from NIB). In theory, the call to `base(viewRootController)` should take care of this; and it does without inheritance, which is *very* strange.

Here's my workaround...

```
public class MyNavigationController : UINavigationController
{
    public MyNavigationController(UIViewController viewRootController) : base()
    {
        AllNavigationControllers.Add(this);
        this.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[]{viewRootController};
    }
}
...
window.RootViewController = new MyNavigationController(new AnotherController());
```

**Not pretty, but now it works on iOS 5 and 6**.

Why is the call to `base(viewRootController)` not working when inheriting but it does when you don't?

(BTW, I am not sure if this issue is specific to Monotouch (now Xamarin.iOS), or is reproducible with equivalent Objective-C code).

Comment: This change the sequence of the calls - which can also differs between iOS releases (we have seen similar issues). Such cases are better reported into http://bugzilla.xamarin.com with an attached, self-contained, test case (sometime it's something else in the project that cause the issue, a self-contained test ensure we can replicate the same issue).

Comment: That's not Objective-C so this q should not be tagged "objective-c". It is only barely even an iOS question. It's off in the world of some weird C++ framework I've never heard of.